# ASPX pages not working in Application within PHP site in IIS8.5

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, iis-8

I have WordPress setup in IIS8.5 and I'm trying to add a ASP.NET 4.0 site as a subfolder/application.  The URL will look like this...

http://mydomain.com/myaspnetapp

I created the Application inside the WordPress site but I can't get the ASPX pages to work.  I have run into many errors, but the latest one is this...

```
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
```

I have setup the Handler Mappings to inherit from the parent and it looks like the handlers are there, but I'm still getting this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is implying that the .Net isn't configured correctly in IIS. Resulting in the static file handler trying to handle your .aspx requests. For me rerunning [the asp.net IIS registration tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) has solved the issue.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: I ran aspnet_regiis -s since I'm on Win2012R2.  It registered everything successfully for my app, but I'm still getting the same error.